# Garbage collection of private method call

Tags: java, memory-management, garbage-collection

I have a problem with memory use in my java app and for the life of me I can't understand why the garbage collector isn't sorting it out. The code is as follows:

```
public void foo() {
    for(int i=0; i<50000; i++) {
        bar(i);
    }
}

private void bar(int i) {
    LargeObject o = new LargeObject();
    ...
    dao.save(o);
}
```

My problem is that instances of LargeObject are not getting garbage collected - to identify this I've profiled with jprofiler and looked at the heap. LargeObject instances are never referenced by class variables, in fact they're not referenced anywhere outside of `bar()`. I'm clutching at straws I feel but could this be related to where the transactions start/end? I've tried changing `bar()` to public and annotating with `Propogation.REQUIRES_NEW` and also changing the annotation on `foo()` to `Propogation.NEVER` to no avail.

The code inside the dao looks like this:

```
public void save(LargeObject o) {
    hibernateTemplate.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(o);
}
```

The garbage collection definitely runs as I see it's activity in jprofiler. `foo()` takes about 30 mins, `bar()` takes 36ms, garbage collection spikes roughly every 60 secs.

To answer the question why I know for sure they're not being garbage collected - nothing in the system references LargeObject yet I see instances of them on the heap increasing as `foo()` is executing.

Comment: How do you know that the instances aren't being collected?  If these are large / complicated objects have you ensured that they are not being referenced by something?  Also, has the garbage collector even run?  If you run in a tight loop, the GC might not get a chance to do any work.

Comment: I seem to remember something about large objects only being collected during a full GC.

Comment: try commenting line: `dao.save(o);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently they are referenced by your JPA provider (or whatever is hiding behind the `dao.save()`). You do let the reference outside, hence your control over it is lost. Whether you do it in a private/public method does not matter.

You might want to share more information about this "DAO".

Comment: Thanks for your input - I hadn't considered that hibernate might be keeping hold of it. Please see the updated question showing the code behind the save method. Have you come across this before?

Answer (score 2):

I'd add to @MaDa's answer that the loop might cause the burden on the unique session that had to cache all the `Large Objects` instances. You should consider either : flushing the session after save, or use a new session, or a cleared session for each `LargeObject` If they are not related

Reading the section on [Batch Processing](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/batch.html) may help you understand your problem